# Spring Boot GraphQL can't load schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am using the following example with Spring Boot 2+ and GraphQL but I am getting the error below when loading graphiql, the schema doesn't load.

https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-boot-graphql-query-example

The code works through a POST call from postman but from Graphiql.

```
@RestController
public class GraphQLController {

    private GraphQLService graphQLService;

    public GraphQLController(GraphQLService graphQLService) {
        this.graphQLService = graphQLService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/graphql")
    public ExecutionResult graphQl(@RequestBody String query) {
        ExecutionResult result = graphQLService.getGraphQL().execute(query);
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Invalid Syntax : offending token '\"query\"' at line 1 column 1",
      "sourcePreview": "{\"query\":\"\\n  query IntrospectionQuery {\\n    __schema {\\n      queryType { name }\\n      mutationType { name }\\n      types {\\n        ...FullType\\n      }\\n      directives {\\n        name\\n        description\\n        locations\\n        args {\\n          ...InputValue\\n        }\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n\\n  fragment FullType on __Type {\\n    kind\\n    name\\n    description\\n    fields(includeDeprecated: true) {\\n      name\\n      description\\n      args {\\n        ...InputValue\\n      }\\n      type {\\n        ...TypeRef\\n      }\\n      isDeprecated\\n      deprecationReason\\n    }\\n    inputFields {\\n      ...InputValue\\n    }\\n    interfaces {\\n      ...TypeRef\\n    }\\n    enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {\\n      name\\n      description\\n      isDeprecated\\n      deprecationReason\\n    }\\n    possibleTypes {\\n      ...TypeRef\\n    }\\n  }\\n\\n  fragment InputValue on __InputValue {\\n    name\\n    description\\n    type { ...TypeRef }\\n    defaultValue\\n  }\\n\\n  fragment TypeRef on __Type {\\n    kind\\n    name\\n    ofType {\\n      kind\\n      name\\n      ofType {\\n        kind\\n        name\\n        ofType {\\n          kind\\n          name\\n          ofType {\\n            kind\\n            name\\n            ofType {\\n              kind\\n              name\\n              ofType {\\n                kind\\n                name\\n                ofType {\\n                  kind\\n                  name\\n                }\\n              }\\n            }\\n          }\\n        }\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n\"}\n",
      "offendingToken": "\"query\"",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 1,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "errorType": "InvalidSyntax",
      "path": null,
      "extensions": null
    }
  ],
  "dataPresent": false,
  "extensions": null
}
```

Comment: Added more details to my answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own object with properties query, operationName and arg.

```
public class Data {
    private String query;

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}

@PostMapping("/graphql")
public ExecutionResult graphQl(@RequestBody Data query) {
    ExecutionResult result = graphQLService.getGraphQL().execute(query.getQuery());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: there are end point named ghrapql/schema.json this should genrated when I set the path 

graphql.servlet.mapping=/graphql
graphiql.endpoint=/graphql

but it loaded one time and now it now found anymore

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're using a strange stack. While `graphql-java-tools` has up to recently lived under the `com.graphql-java` groupId in Maven, it is actually a completely separate stack. The more recent releases are published under a new groupId `com.graphql-java-kickstart` to avoid future confusion.

Now, if you're already using `graphql-java-tools`, the Starter you need is `com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter` as they're intended to be used together.

The starter you're using (`com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter`) is intended to be used with pure `graphql-java`. You just need to wire in a bean of type `GraphQL`. See [the official tutorial](https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/) for more details.

They *can* be made to work together, mind you, it's just a suboptimal combo.

Now, the reason you're getting this error is that your HTTP endpoint (Spring Controller) does not comply with the [GraphQL-over-HTTP specification](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/), and GraphiQL is expecting that (specifically, GraphiQL is using the [POST variety](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request)). Postman isn't, so it passes.

The best way it to change your backend to expect a JSON object in request, with the following shape:

```
{
  "query": "...",
  "operationName": "...",
  "variables": { "myVariable": "someValue", ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using GraphQL with Spring Boot 2+, there is no need to create a POST API endpoint **/graphql**. Here are the steps to follow:

**Step 1:**
Add dependencies in pom.xml for GraphQL:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Step 2**: Create GraphQL schema:
Here is a sample GraphQL schema:

```
type Employee {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  department: String! 
  salary: Int!  
} 

type Query { 
  getEmployees: [Employee]! 
  countEmployees: Float!
  getEmployee(id: ID):Employee
} 

type Mutation { 
    newEmployee (name: String!, department: String!, salary: Int!): Employee
    deleteEmployee(id: ID): Boolean!
}
```

**Step 3**: Create GraphQL classes and mark them with the annotation `@Component`
Here is a sample class:

```
@Component
public class EmployeeQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeservice;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employeeservice.findAll();
    }

    public long countEmployees() {
        return employeeservice.count();
    }

    public Optional<Employee> getEmployee(final int id) {
        return employeeservice.findById(id);
    }
}
```

After this, the endpoint **/graphql** is automatically available and GraphiQL will also work without any issues.
I have written a simple GraphQL and Spring Boot example in a blog post with working code in GitHub. Please refer to: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2019/11/graphql-spring-boot-and-mysql-tutorial.html